# How to override the category template on the /shop/ page when showing filtered products?

Tags: woocommerce

I already created a function that will filter products using URL parameters and display them on the /shop/ page. That works fine.

But, that only works if the products template is set on the WooCommerce `/shop/` page.

In my case the requirement is to have the category list set as default template on the `/shop/` page. That means I need to override that template and show the filtered product list, when I run a product query with URL parameters.

(eg. `example.com/shop/?param1=foo&param2=bar`)

I tried following code (and some iterations), but I'm stuck and have no clue how to override the default template when a product filter is applied:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', [$this, 'my_include_template_function'], 10, 3 );

public function my_change_template_function($template, $template_name, $template_path)
{
    if (!empty($_GET['param1']) && is_shop() && $template_name == 'content-product_cat.php') {
        return wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
    } else {
        return $template;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the source of the categories loop is added in to the loop start [via a filter][1]

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 'woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories' );
```

and the [`woocommerce_maybe_short_product_subcategories()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/17367c36698b18bcb4a1d92d55c290ffdd57d812/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2374) function changes the output based on the:

```
$display_type = woocommerce_get_loop_display_mode();
```

However, the [`woocommerce_get_loop_display_mode()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/17367c36698b18bcb4a1d92d55c290ffdd57d812/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2326) result isn't filterable directly.

But it relies on some values from `get_option()` (since the setting is in the customizer) and `get_option()` is filterable via [`option_$option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_option/)

So a potential way to tell WooCommerce *not* to display the categories when you have a particular `$_GET` parameter, you could filter the shop display mode option to be `products` when that parameter is detected in the URL. Like this:

```
/**
 * Filter shop display type.
 *
 * @param string $value - 'products' | 'subcategories' | 'both'
 * @return string
 */
function kia_woocommerce_shop_page_display( $value ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['param1'] ) {
        $value = 'products';
    }
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'option_woocommerce_shop_page_display', 'kia_woocommerce_shop_page_display' );
```